# Can't update fullcalendar(fullcalendar js) main event object after update particular event in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using javascript fullcalendar in angular js,

i want to update event title on click particular event,so i have used

```
eventClick:$scope.alertOnEditEvent

$scope.alertOnEditEvent = function( event, jsEvent, view ){

          var title = prompt('Event Title:', event.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });

    if (title){
        event.title = title;
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
    }

    console.log($scope.events);

}
```

i can see new title in fullcalendar event portion but i can not see new event title in main events object in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed that.

```
 var events = $('.calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
 console.log(events);
```